# Find the number of distinct integers in the collection of first $500$ terms of each of the arithemetic progressions $\{1,4,...\}$ and $\{9,14,...\}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, arithmetic-progressions

Let $1,4,...$ and $9,14,...$ be two arithmetic progressions. Then the number of distinct integers in the collection of first $500$ terms of each of progressions is $$A. 833,\space  B. 835,\space C.837 ,\space D. 901$$

My solution goes like this:

> The two A.P.'s general term might be represented as $$1+(n_1-1)3=9+(n_2-1)5\implies 3n_1-5n_2=6\implies 3(n_1-2)=5n_2.$$ Hence, $3|n_2\implies n_2=3k$ and so, $3(n_1-2)=5n_2=15k\implies n_1-2=5k\implies n_1=5k+2.$ Now, $5k+2\leq 500\implies 5k\leq 498\implies k\leq 99.$ Due to this, we may conclude, $99$ terms of both the A.P.'s are similar. So, total number of common terms in both the A.P's is : $99+99=198$ and the number of distinct terms in both the A.P's in total is: $1000-198=802.$

However, I feel something's wrong with my solution, as my solution, is not matching with any of the options. But I don’t understand where is the solution going wrong, if that's the case. I am not quite getting it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've done a great job, and almost have it. However, note that determining the number of distinct terms involves removing just the *additional* repeated terms, not all of the terms that have been repeated (i.e., the "total number of common terms" as you call it). As [JonathanZ supports MonicaC's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4670821/let-1-4-and-9-14-be-two-arithmetic-progressions-then-the-number-of#comment9872035_4670827) states, you have

> answered the question "how many numbers are there that show up in only one of the series". And I don't think anyone could argue that that's what "distinct" means.

In particular, you've instead determined the number of *unique* terms, i.e., how many terms that appear just once.

You've found there were $99$ terms that were repeated so, since each was repeated only once, the total needs to be reduced by just $99$. This then leaves one copy of each of those terms, which leads to the result being

$$1000 - 99 = 901$$

i.e., answer $D$.

Comment: Yup. The OP has answered the question "how many numbers are there that show up in only one of the series". And I don't think anyone could argues that that's what "distinct" means.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC IMHO, you've stated the situation very well. As such, I've added most of your comment to my answer.

Comment: Nice. Glad you found it useful. (Though maybe you should remove my typo of "argues" for "argue"?)

Comment: @JohnOmielan Ohh...Silly me! Thanks for your excellent clarifications!

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thanks a lot! I do get it now!